# Interval set through content script being cleared by webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, I have a setInterval in the content script which checks for changes in the webpage after every 3 seconds.

```
setInterval(detectChange, 3000)

function detectChange(){
    ...
}
```

This works perfectly well for all websites except one ([www.rdio.com](http://www.rdio.com/)). The webpage scripts somehow clears the interval set through the content script.

I thought of putting the setInterval in background script and sending a message to the content script at each interval. But that would require me to track all the tabs in which the content script is running, which does not seem like a good idea.

Please let me know if there is a way around.

Comment: What you describe is impossible. Unless the page navigates away, your content script's context is untouchable by the page. Needs more debugging.

Comment: That was my understanding as well. But I couldn't find any other explanation. The page does not navigate away, because, other parts of the content script still works, such as message listeners and event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancelable task schedulers (`setTimeout`, `setInterval`,  `requestAnimationFrame`, etc.) are apparently tied to a document. Although the script execution context of a content script is isolated from the page, the document is not.

It seems rather weird that a site clears timers that are not created by the site itself. You could try to debug the issue, and check why the site is clearing the timer at all by overriding the `clearTimeout` / `clearInterval` methods.

Here is an example to catch code that clears timers that are not installed by the script itself:

```js
// Run this content script at document_start
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = '(' + function() {
    var clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
    var setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
    var setInterval = window.setInterval;
    // NOTE: This list of handles is NEVER cleared, because it is the
    // only way to keep track of the complete history of timers.
    var handles = [];
    window.setTimeout = function() {
        var handle = setTimeout.apply(this, arguments);
        if (handle) handles.push(handle);
        return handle;
    };
    window.setInterval = function() {
        var handle = setInterval.apply(this, arguments);
        if (handle) handles.push(handle);
        return handle;
    };
    window.clearTimeout = window.clearInterval = function(handle) {
        clearTimeout(handle);
        if (handle && handles.indexOf(handle) === -1) {
            // Print a stack trace for debugging
            console.trace('Cleared non-owned timer!');
            // Or trigger a breakpoint so you can follow the call
            // stack to identify which caller is responsible for
            // clearing unknown timers.
            debugger;
        }
    };
} + ')();';
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.remove();
```

If this shows that the site is buggy, and (for example) clears every even-numbered timer, then you simply call setTimeout twice to resolve the problem.

For example:

```js
Promise.race([
    new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
    }),
    new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
    });
}).then(function() {
    // Any of the timers have fired
});
```

#### If all else fails...

If it turns out that the site clears the timers in an unpredictable way, you could try to use other asynchronous methods or events to schedule tasks, and measure the time between invocations. When a certain time has elapsed, simply trigger your callback. For example, using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) (which is usually called *several times per second*):

```js
function scheduleTask(callback, timeout) {
    timeout = +timeout || 0;
    var start = performance.now();
    function onDone(timestamp) {
        if (timestamp - start >= timeout) callback();
        else requestAnimationFrame(onDone);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(onDone);
}

// Usage example:
console.time('testScheduler');
scheduleTask(function() {
    console.timeEnd('testScheduler');
}, 1000);
```

Or insert an `<iframe>` and create timers in the context of the frame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I debugged as you suggested and got this:
`Cleared non-owned timer!  [VM54028:1]
window.clearTimeout.window.clearInterval [ImageLoader.f79c22ba20b9f32ecc63488859b91348.js:87]
R.Component.create.onLoaded [jquery-1.8.3.c2901e3fdd932a1fc29794aafece65e5.js:3058]
jQuery.event.dispatch [jquery-1.8.3.c2901e3fdd932a1fc29794aafece65e5.js:2676]
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle [(index):129]
nrWrapper`

Looks like, some ImageLoader code in the page is clearing my interval!

Comment: I tried your scheduledTask function using requestAnimationFrame. It is not working either, the callback function runs only once.

Comment: @Samik The callback *should* run only once, because the method is similar to `setTimeout`. Call `scheduleTask` again when the callback is called if you want yo schedule a *periodic task*, like `setInterval`.

Comment: Right! Still I was having some issues with it. Finally, I went for your last suggestion (using <iframe>): `$('<iframe>').css('display','none').appendTo('body')[0].contentWindow.setInterval(detectChange,3000)`. It is working nicely. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That's.. messy with regards to CS/webpage separation. Thanks for weighing in on the topic.